# Smartdiagram: Connected constellation diagram doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I used the following code directly from a *smartdiagram* manual but it didn't produce a **connected** constellation diagram. Could you please tell me why? Thanks in advance.

```
      \documentclass[11pt]{article}
      \usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
      \usepackage{smartdiagram}
      \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
      \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
      \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
      \usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}


      \begin{document}
      \begin{center}
      \smartdiagramset{planet color=orange!60,
      distance planet-satellite=1cm
      }
      \smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]
      {Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add,Check}
      \end{center}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), just modify  `distance planet-satellite` key default `3.5cm`.

Comment: @salim Thank you very much. The codes of  manual (p18)  are wrong.

Comment: @SalimBou Do you want to answer?

Comment: @hamachi Did you report it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments